# Convert custom_filters_score query to newest function_score with ElasticSearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

In order to update a query created with an old version of ES (previous to v0.94) i am presented with a query called like this:

```
            json.query.bool.should = [
                {
                    "custom_filters_score" : {
                        "query": {
                            "match_all" : {}
                        },
                        "filters": filters,
                        "score_mode" : "multiply"
                    }
                }
            ];
```

I'm trying to update this to the newest function_score, but i've found the documentation isn't exactly clear about some of the fields, my non-functional try:

```
            json.query.bool.should = [
                {
                    "function_score" : {
                        "query": {
                            "match_all" : {}
                        },
                        "functions": filters,
                        "score_mode" : "multiply"
                    }
                }
            ];
```

Being **filters**

```
            var filters = [
            {
                "filter":{
                    "numeric_range" : {
                        "population" : {
                            "from" : "1000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "boost":2
            },
            {
                "filter":{
                    "numeric_range" : {
                        "population" : {
                            "from" : "10000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "boost":5
            },
            {
                "filter":{
                    "numeric_range" : {
                        "population" : {
                            "from" : "100000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "boost":3
            }
        ];
```

I am presented with this error after removing "boost" from "filters" and trying a call:

```
Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: NullPointerException; }]","status":500}
```

I've tried removing "boost" from "filters, and sending it as is, but i'm still unable to convert the query, i would like to update this and not to go back to an old version of ES.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm running into the same issue right now!

Comment: No, but i got the "tumbleweed" badge in StackOverflow... haha.. sorry..